# How does ssh-agent start on boot?

Tags: fedora, startup, ssh-agent

I've just installed Fedora, and noticed that `ssh-agent` is already started on boot. Out of curiosity, I checked `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` and didn't find it listed as a service there.

I didn't find it in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` either.

**Where does it come from?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current Fedora, `ssh-agent` starts as part of `gnome-keyring`. I don't have Fedora at hand now, but it is mentioned in the release notes of gnome-keyring:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/-/tags/3.27.92

The bug discussing this change, its pros and cons, is available here:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775981